# Installation of perl DBD-MySQL Package on solaris 10 without the presence of C compiler

Tags: perl

I compile the perl DBI package on solaris 10 say SERVER1 with say perl 5.8.10 installed on it and create DBI.

Now I copy the above DBI.so and the DBI.pm files to another solaris SERVER2 machine with the same hardware and the same version of perl.

Can I be sure that the DBI package will run smoothly and I will not get any run-time errors in future ?

Please note that I dont have the flexibilty to install a C compiler SERVER2.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware does not matter so much as you think, the operating system abstracts this away nicely. For binary compatibility, the minor version must match, so the other Perl must also be from the 5.8 series. (By the way, 5.8.9 was the last one, 5.8.10 does not exist.)

As you're talking about a dynamic library, the integration on the C level is much more important. Are the libraries referenced from the `DBI.so` compatible (e.g. `libc.so` has the same version on both machines)? Check with the `ldd` command.

In case of mismatches, you will not get run-time errors, but very obvious crashes at compile time when perl attempt to load DBI.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as in this question: [How can I install Perl modules on a restricted server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206035/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-on-a-restricted-server/3206152#3206152) -- install your modules and libraries on a system with the same architecture (using a special installation directory), then copy the modules over to your restricted system.

You'll need a C compiler *somewhere* (unless you can find pre-compiled binaries of the .so or .dll files you need), but it doesn't have to be on the intended target.